# Dealing with empty numeric bindings

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a `WPF` application with an `int` property in my View-Model that looks like this:

```
private int _port;
public int Port
{
    get { return _port; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _port, value); }
}
```

and my view is bound to it like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Port, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

My problem is that whenever a user clears the textbox text I get the following error:

> Value '' could not be converted.

This causes the binding to not update the property and therefore any rules that I set for a command `CanExecute` logic does not apply.
Is there any way to override this behavior (without changing the type of the property to `Nullable`)?

**UPDATE**
I've tried using the [FallbackValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.fallbackvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) or a converter but this 2 change the value to some pre-defined default value which is not applicable in my case.

Comment: When the text box is cleared, the "value" would be either empty or null, so in you need a check before you parse in the "value" such as string.IsNullOrWhitespace(value.ToString()) ? 0 :value

Comment: @Jegan: where should OP place this checking?

Comment: Look at this: [http://www.codecisions.com/custom-ivalueconverter-for-binding-a-wpf-textbox-to-an-integer/](http://www.codecisions.com/custom-ivalueconverter-for-binding-a-wpf-textbox-to-an-integer/)

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways is to use control, designed to deal with numbers, like [`IntegerUpDown`](http://doc.xceedsoft.com/products/XceedWpfToolkit/Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit~Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.IntegerUpDown.html):

```
<xctk:IntegerUpDown Value="{Binding MyValue}"/>
```

Another way is to write [`IValueConverter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to use in binding.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the FallBackValue of the Binding.

see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.fallbackvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

So something like this migth work:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Port, FallBackValue="0", UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

That's assuming you want the value to be zero when empty.

Comment: note that the type is `int`  so you should do `FallBackValue=0`

Comment: this doesn't change the result (also when applying what @M.kazemAkhgary suggested)

Comment: You might need to combine it with the TargetNullValue also to get it to work.

Try TargetNullValue={x:Static sys:String.Empty}

Comment: still the same. I guess that `TargetNullValue` has no effect since my property not Nullable

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a converter ? 
It'll let you do whatever you want with the value, and when it's clear, you can set it to a default of your choice.

Here's a sample from this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/768427/The-big-MVVM-Template):

```
class IntConverter : IValueConverter
{
  /// <summary>
  /// should try to parse your int or return 0 otherwise.
  /// </summary>
  public object Convert(object value,Type targetType,object parameter,CultureInfo culture)
  {
    int temp_int;
    return (Int32.TryParse(value, out temp_int)
       ? temp_int
       : 0;
  }

  public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
}
```

To use the above converter, have this in your Xaml:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Port, 
                UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}",
                Converter={StaticResource IntConverter }}" 
/>
```

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
public int Port
{
    get { return _port; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _port, string.IsNullOrWhitespace(value.ToString())?0 :value); 
}
```

Comment: `string.IsNullOrWhitespace(value.ToString())` doesn't make much sense. Since `int` is a value type, and always has some value, `ToString` never returns `null` or `string.Empty`. Moreover, when binding convertion fails, binding engine doesn't call property setter.